# Mongoose schema field definition issue (keywords: nodejs, req.body, extend, field, type)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, extend

It took me half an hour to figure out what was the issue, so I need to post this issue to save your precious time.

---

I have a schema, its definition is as below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: String,
    desc: String,
    price: Number,

    owner: { // this field would be filled with req.session.user
        uid: {type: Number, index: true},
        nickname: String,
        contact: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ItemSchema', ItemSchema);
```

---

And then, if front-end send a post request as below:

```
console.log( req.body );
/*
    {
        title: 'apple',
        desc: 'nice apple',
        price: 100
    }
*/
```

---

My Express router code, written:

```
...
req.body.owner = req.session.user;

var newItem = new ItemSchema( req.body );

newItem.save(function(err, re) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(re);
});
```

---

After that, my ItemSchema had one record(document) added. But it didn't contain the user field, just as below:

```
> db.item.findOne();
{
    _id: ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    title: 'apple',
    desc: 'nice apple',
    price: 100
}
```

---

It was so strange!!! Where is the user field???

---

I have to highlight that if console.log( req.body ), it does contain user field.

---

At first I created a solution as below:

```
req.body.user = {
    uid: req.session.user.uid,
    nickname: req.session.user.nickname,
    contact: req.session.user.contact
}; // It works, but looks stupid
```

---

And then I use underscore:

```
var newItem = new ItemSchema( _.extend(req.body, {user: req.session.user}) ); // It doesn't work, I don't know why
```

---

Finally, I figured out it must be the problem of Mongoose Schema Definition, so I tried:

```
var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: String,
    desc: String,
    price: Number,

    owner: {type: { // here is the key!!!
        uid: {type: Number, index: true},
        nickname: String,
        contact: String
    }}
});
```

---

Since then, no more problem, I can code:

```
req.body.user = req.session.user; // ok
```

---

But I found my previous definition should be ok, as http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html introduces:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var blogSchema = new Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: String,
  body:   String,
  comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  hidden: Boolean,
  meta: { // here, same data structure with my user field
    votes: Number,
    favs:  Number
  }
});
```

---

So, what was the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a [subdocument schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) in Mongoose

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    uid: {type: Number, index: true},
    nickname: String,
    contact: String
}, {_id: false})

var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: String,
    desc: String,
    price: Number,

    owner: UserSchema
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a type of Mongoose: Schema.Types.Mixed. Thus:

```
...
user: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed}, // ok, but no index set
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I came to realize that the problem is, req.session.user is not a ordinary object, let' s see how did it come :

```
// UserSchema.js
...
UserSchema.statics.getSessionFields = function(uid, cb) {
    this.findById(uid).select('uid nickname contact').exec(cb);
};
...


// app.js
...
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var UserDB = require('path/to/UserSchema.js');

    UserDB.getSessionFields(12345, function(err, re) {
        req.session.user = re; // here is the problem
        next();
    });
});
...
```

---

This **re** is a ***query object***, not the object just contains uid、nickname、contact.

---

So the ultimate solution is :

```
UserDB.getSessionFields(12345, function(err, re) {
    req.session.user = re.toJSON(); // just the way as Backbone
    next();
});
```